# How Google Chrome is best than other browsers even though Firefox is good in handling privacy policy?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I am a student of computer science class-10th and i am learning graphic designing in my vacations and it was just first module and i installed Firefox and google chrome in my laptop, now i am confused which browser should i use through my learning. Can anyone help me to suggest one of them based on the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Is Firefox Really Better Than Chrome? Firefox is a more private and secure browser than Chrome, but Chrome is faster and contains more features. Is Firefox Safer Than Chrome? Both browsers are safe, but Firefox's tracking protection is more comprehensive than Chrome's.